# Coverage.py - source code file isn't covered by all the tests from the test file

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, code-coverage

After finishing my tests, i have to use coverage to find out the percentage of the coverage. So, i have one file (source code) called `connectors.py` and the test file called `test_connectors.py`, in which i have a lots of tests (21 - bellow you can see only 2 of them, but this doesn't matter:

**Test file**

```html
class FileCompare():...



class TestParser(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_TRS_ABU_INOUT_001(self):
        current_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
        head, tail = ntpath.split(current_path)
        os.system('connectors.py -in ' + head + '\\tests\TRS.ABU.INOUT.001\input -out ' + head + '\\tests\TRS.ABU.INOUT.001\output')
        self.assertTrue(FileCompare.checkParsing(head + '\\tests\TRS.ABU.INOUT.001\input', head + '\\tests\TRS.ABU.INOUT.001\output\\result.log', 'is'))

    def test_TRS_ABU_FUNC_0001(self):
        current_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
        head, tail = ntpath.split(current_path)
        os.system('connectors.py -in ' + head + '\\tests\TRS.ABU.FUNC.0001\input -out ' + head + '\\tests\TRS.ABU.FUNC.0001\output')
        self.assertTrue(FileCompare.isOutput(head + '\\tests\TRS.ABU.FUNC.0001\output'))
```

My problem is next: after running the coverage for `connectors.py` file, in the generated html report file it shows me the code covered only by the last function from `test_connectors.py` (in my example, the last function is `test_TRS_ABU_FUNC_0001` which does not pass through the whole source code)

In my source code i've imported Coverage as a module `from coverage import Coverage` and at the end of the code i've used:

```html
if name == "main": 
cov = Coverage() 
cov.start() 
main() 
cov.stop() 
cov.html_report(directory="coverage-html")
```

Well, in my test_connectors.py i use coverage like this: `coverage run --source=dir my_program.py`

What can i do for coverage.py to takes all the tests functions from `test_connectors.py` for verifying the coverage of them in my source file?

Comment: You haven't shown how you are running your tests, and how you are invoking coverage.

Comment: In my source code i've imported Coverage as a module ('from coverage import Coverage') and at the end of the code i've used if __name__ == "__main__": cov = Coverage() cov.start() main() cov.stop() cov.html_report(directory="coverage-html"). Well, in my test_connectors.py i use coverage like this: coverage run --source=dir my_program.py

Comment: You'll need to add these details to the question, it's impossible to understand like this.  BUT: you almost certainly don't need to use the coverage API. Just run your test runner with the coverage command-line.